# Erro ao inserir valor monetário no banco

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2012

estou tentando salvar o valor 137421,20 em uma tabela do SqlServer com um campo do tipo Numeric(8,2). Porém recebo um erro com a descrição:

**"Valor de parâmetro 137421,20 está fora do intervalo."**

Estou tentando inserir o valor no campo **ArquivoTrailler_TotalValor**

Estou usando o Entity Framework e meu model está com o seguinte código:

```
 public partial class ARQUIVO_GERADO_TRAILLER
    {
        public int ID_Arquivo { get; set; }
        public string ArquivoTrailler_Conteudo { get; set; }
        public int ArquivoTrailler_TotalLinhas { get; set; }
        public decimal ArquivoTrailler_TotalValor { get; set; }
    }
```

A chamada na classe que está inserindo os valores está com o código abaixo:

```
objArquivoGeradoTrailler.ID_Arquivo = 90;
objArquivoGeradoTrailler.ArquivoTrailler_Conteudo = "texto";
objArquivoGeradoTrailler.ArquivoTrailler_TotalLinhas = 477;
objArquivoGeradoTrailler.ArquivoTrailler_TotalValor = 137421,20;

db.ARQUIVO_GERADO_TRAILLER.Add(objArquivoGeradoTrailler);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Consigo inserir esse valor direto na tabela do banco, através de um script insert. Mas alimentando o atributo ArquivoTrailler_TotalValor que é do tipo decimal recebo o erro descrito acima.

Comment: Mude para `137421.20` Note o ponto no lugar da vírgula.

Comment: @bigown já fiz o teste, e o erro persiste.

Comment: Pode ser alguma configuração de seu modelo de dados via Fluent API que pode estar determinando o Range do seu campo. Se possível compartilhe toda a sua classe de contexto, ou pelo menos o `OnModelCreating`

Comment: Consegui identificar o erro, estava atualizando o campo no banco de dados mas não o arquivo edmx. Bastou aumentar a propriedade hasprecision e funcionou.

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite,

Tente utilizar o "." ao invés da "," no valor do decimal.

```
objArquivoGeradoTrailler.ArquivoTrailler_TotalValor = 137421.20;
```

ou pode utilizar o

```
objArquivoGeradoTrailler.ArquivoTrailler_TotalValor = decimal.Parse(137421,20);
```